# Как уменьшить задержку между появлением .onion сайта в сети и получением к нему доступа?

Tags: linux, windows, парсер, tor

Есть .onion сайт. Он иногда уходит в оффлайн (отключается сервер за ненадобностью). Иногда возвращается онлайн.
Есть скрипт, который парсит этот сайт, используя в качестве прокси тор, собранный из сорцов (на линухе).
Так вот, после того, как сайт появляется онлайн, и я могу открыть его из под виндовса обычным TorBrowser, есть задержка в несколько минут (от минуты до получаса), пока он станет доступен и до консольного тора. Почему? Как эту задержку убрать? Перезагрузка тора, принудительная смена ноды и т.п. не помогают.
Мб. можно обновить какой-то хеш или что-то в этом духе?

Comment: резолвер мне кажетя